# Getting variables out of Dynamic Modules after restoring the program

Tags: dynamic, scoping

The scrap of code below [from *Mathematica's Help* on `DynamicModules`] generates a `Pane` of `Locator`s, and a line showing the interpolation between the datapoints.

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
             Dynamic[Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x], {x, 0, 3}, 
                          PlotRange -> 3]
 ]]]
```

When the program is saved,and reloaded, the `Plot` persists with the then current values of the points.

Suppose, after reloading the file (but not reinitializing the `DynamicModule`), I want to use the values of the points (which I moved in interacting with the program before saving it).  In otherwords, I'd like to be able to access a list of the modified points with, perhaps, new functions.

I realize I could just read out variables in the original function, store them, then load them as part of the initialization procedure when restarting a program a second time, but this in effect means running the original program history completely again.  In complex programs, with lots of potential branches, this could be tedious and error prone.

Any solution?  `DynamicModule` would seem to attempt to address this problem by saving variables, but, for example, in the above code scrap, I want to get numerical values of the point positions for use in other parts of the program, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `Setting`:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly something I was searching for... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to include a mechanism for saving the state of the `DynamicModule` in the code.  For instance, here's a button that will print a cell that contains code to initialize a global variable to the value of `pts`:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}}}, 
 Column[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
    Dynamic[Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x], {x, 0, 3}, 
      PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> Medium]]], 
   Button["Save", 
    With[{p = pts}, CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Defer[points = p], "Input"]]]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One could change the action to simply setting the global variable, in this way:

```
Button["Save", points = p]
```

Comment: Michael 's answer does work for the example given, and I appreciate the result.  My actual problem is a bit more complicated in that I have about 10 graphs, each with about 10 locators, which ultimately are the variables of interest for a calculation.  While I can (and it looks like, probably will) use this method, keeping track of a 10 lists and corresponding file[s] associated with this program seems a bit inelegant.  @Kuba 's Setting idea works well in the example given (which is slightly different from my actual usage), but I can't (yet) make it work with my actual code.  I'll update...