# $CellContext issue while trying to export the current output of a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, symbols, conversion

Having just read this question

- [Getting variables out of Dynamic Modules after restoring the program](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/getting-variables-out-of-dynamic-modules-after-restoring-the-program?rq=1)

and the Kuba's answer I'm trying to optimize my workflow. I'm writing a Mathematica notebook to create and export a series of graphics. These graphics can be *static* or *dynamic*, i.e. the result of a `Manipulate`; what I want to export from a `Manipulate` is the current state, not the initial state, so I don't want to evaluate the cells that generate the `Manipulate` every time I need to export the graphics.

I want to be able to export a single graphics, by clicking a button near the graphics for example, and to export all the graphics at once, by clicking a button at the beginning of the notebook for example. As stated, I don't want to evaluate all the notebook or the initialization cells to accomplish this task.

What I think to do is to add a button near to each input cell that create a graphics (how by stylesheet?); this button should read and export the graphics in the output cell in it's current Manipulate state.

I think I can also create a function that search all these outputs in the current notebook, thanks to some tag or style, and virtually press any of these button in some way.

**First question: what do you think about this strategy? Any issue, suggestion, better approach?**

I'm experimenting with these ideas but I encountered a problem. I globally defined a variable containing a series of options tio apply to all graphics and this cause an issue I don't understand. A minimal example:

```
plotOpts = Sequence[GridLines -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"];
g = Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Evaluate@plotOpts], {{n, 1}, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and, in the subsequent cell:

```
Setting @ ToExpression @ First @ NotebookRead @ PreviousCell[]
```

but I get this error

> ```
> During evaluation of In[307]:= Plot::nonopt: Options expected 
> (instead of $CellContext`plotOpts) beyond position 2 in 
> Plot[Sin[n$175064 x],{x,0,2 \[Pi]},$CellContext`plotOpts]. 
> An option must be a rule or a list of rules.
> ```

**There is some *CellContext* issue. After reading the only question on this site about this "placeholder" I cannot figure out the cause of the problem and how to solve it.**

**Second question: there is a solution to this?**

I noticed that adding `SaveDefinition->True` doesn't solve, and, if possible, I don't want to be forced to use this option.

Comment: Just use With: `With[{plotOpts = 
   Sequence[GridLines -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]},
 g = Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Evaluate@plotOpts], {{n, 1}, 1, 
    5}]]`

Comment: @RolfMertig I cannot use `With`, not in this way at least. I set `plotOpts` once at the beginning of my notebook and the I need to use it many times in many different places..

Comment: @unlikely so use `With[{localopts = plotOpts}, Hold[localopts]]`

Comment: @Kuba Is this the only way? I.e. changing the way I currently generate all my plots?

Comment: @unlikely Any comments about the answer?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for your answer. A bit intricate. I still don't understand what is the cause of this  `$CellContext`-issue, but I suppose there is something wrong in how I made things If there is no other simpler way than using this trick. I still hope someone else gives a simpler answer, but, if nothing happens, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, assuming you can't change the way your plots are done, let's use brute force:

```
Setting @ ToExpression @ ToExpression @ ReplaceAll[
    ToBoxes @ NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]][[1, 1]],
    s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "$CellContext`*" ~~ Except["$"]] :> StringDrop[s, 12]
]
```

[image]